# How/where did Stanislaw Lem learn advanced mathematics?

Tags: stanislaw-lem

It seems, based on some of his writings, that Stanislaw Lem had some background in non-basic mathematics. For example the poem ["Love and Tensor Algebra"](http://www.aleph.se/Trans/Cultural/Art/tensor.html) from *The Cyberiad*.

As far as I know, he never formally studied mathematics, so I'm wondering — is it known how or when he became interested in mathematics, and how he learned it?

Comment: One would not have to learn any advanced mathematics to write a poem like that. It would be enough to read a popular book about mathematics to pick up some jargon and some names.

Comment: See also https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2976/139 "Mathematics or gibberish? Understanding a description of an alien message in His Master's Voice"

Answer (score 12):

[His entry in the Polish Wikipedia](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanis%C5%82aw_Lem) says he read *Cybernetics or Control and Communication in the Animal and the Machine* by N. Wiener and *A Mathematical Theory of Communication* by C. E. Shannon when he was an assistant at the Jagiellonian University (1948-50).

Cited source is a book *[Świat na krawędzi](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9Awiat_na_kraw%C4%99dzi)*, a series of interviews with Lem, written by Tomasz Fiałkowski (p. 56-57 specifically).